# amazon s3 virtual hosting of bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have uploaded a file on s3 using paperclip.. the file upload process works fine..
Now i wanted to download it. In my model i have set my `:s3_host_alias`.. now as the file is private.. so if i am trying to fetch the file using paperclip url method... it's giving me access denied error...

and if i am using `S3Object.url_for` method then the url return is `s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/path_of_file`.

I don't want tht s3.amazonaws.com to be shown in the url so used `:s3_host_alias` in my model
and created a CNAME inmy DNS server... now if i am directly using `@object.url` then its giving the correct url but throws access denied error. because i guess the access_key and signature is not passed..

Is there a way to fetch private file from s3 using paperclip by using canonical url..

Answer (score 0):

I don't use paperclip, but yes, you can sign a S3 request using a virtual hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using Paperclip and the AWS::S3 gem. Paperclip set up everything fine for non-authenticated requests. But falling back to AWS::S3 to generate an authenticated URL didn't use the S3 host alias.

You can pass AWS::S3 a server option on connect, but I didn't need or want a connection just to get the URL. I also couldn't see a way to set it via configuration (so it would apply outside of a connection). Even glancing at the source, it looks like it's non-configurable.

So, I created a monkey patch. My Ruby-fu (and maybe my OO-fu) aren't super high, so there may be a better way to do this, but it works for what I need. Basically, I pass url_for an `:s3_host_alias` param on the option hash, and then the monkey patch uses that if it's passed. If it's passed, it also has to remove the bucket from the path that's generated.

So....

You can create this 1-line file, `RAILS_ROOT/initializers/load_patches.rb`, to load all patches in `RAILS_ROOT/lib`:

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'patches', '**', '*.rb')].sort.each { |patch| require(patch) }
```

Then create the file `RAILS_ROOT/lib/patches/aws.rb` with this code:

http://pastie.org/1622881

And you can call for an authenticated url with something along these lines (Configuration is a custom class for storing, natch, configuration values) :

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(media.path(style || media.default_style), media.bucket_name, :expires_in => expires_in, :use_ssl => false, :s3_host_alias => Configuration.s3_host_alias)
```